# Is there any possible way to view more detailed information about methods in VisualVM?

Tags: java, jvm, visualvm

For example, say I have a method doThis() that VisualVM shows has the greatest "Self time". Would it be possible to view the time or CPU usage of specific lines of code or method calls within doThis()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, profiling happens on method entry and exit, and not on every line of code. You will have to split off half the lines into separate methods if you want to see which half is the most work-intensive.

Comment: Of course not. VisualVM uses the same code base as NetBeans. :-)